# Batch File issue, recieving "The Filename, Directory Name, Or Volume Label Syntax Is Incorrect"

Tags: loops, if-statement, goto, netsh, winpe

I'm recieving the following error when I run my batch file
"The Filename, Directory Name, Or Volume Label Syntax Is Incorrect"

My batch file runs fine, but this error pops up 25 times and then proceeds.  I can't figure out what i'm missing here.  Below is my code:

```
::This batch file is used to set a static IP and launch Windows Recovery Environment

@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

::Setting Static IP Address & DNS Address

netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" static 10.11.111.110 255.255.255.0 10.11.111.249 1

netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static 10.11.101.1 primary

::Verify Network Connection

:chklink

set ipaddr=10.11.107.20

set oldstate=neither

set state=down

for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (

    if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set state=up
)

if not !state!==!oldstate! (

    echo.Link is !state!

    set oldstate=!state!

)

REM ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:


SET answer=!state!

IF %answer%==up (

goto recovery


) ELSE (

IF %answer%==down (
::Set static address on NIC 2 if NIC 1 failed

netsh interface ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection 2" static 10.11.111.110 255.255.255.0 10.11.111.249 1

netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection 2" static 10.11.101.1 primary

goto chklink


)
)

::Launch Windows Recovery Environment

:recovery

cls

x:\sources\recovery\recenv.exe

exit
```

===========================================================

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Derek

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the `::` comments and replacing them with `rem` ones. I've had difficulties in the past with using these inside control structures like `if`.

See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php) for an explanation. In fact that [whole site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/) is an incredible resource for `cmd.exe` scripters who, for some reason or another, aren't allowed to install CygWin.

Failing that, comment out the `@echo off` and see what it's doing when those errors appear.

Comment: @Double, take out the `echo off` and you should be able to _see_ the command that's running when the errors appear.